# Raspberry Pi Zero as Hardware Bypass

Tags: usb, hardware, linux, serial

My girlfriend has been working on a project for a high level university CS class. The requirements are that input is take from a gaming controller, steering wheel, et al, and sent simultaneously to a computer running a game simulation via USB and to a database via ethernet.

We have managed to read the raw input data from the controller in `/dev/` and output it to `stdout`. The real struggle is determining how to forward this data out over a TTL to USB or similar connector in order for Windows to see only the controller device, and not the Raspberry Pi.

In short, can I get an answer of "Yes, this is possible, this should point you in the right direction" or "you only have to do this." OR "No, this is not possible, for these reasons: ..."

Comment: Please clean your answer. The panicky intro isn't particularly appropriate to the site.

Comment: @Jacobm001 What panicky? After you edited your comment, I've made changes to the post.

Comment: why is it relevant that your girlfriend is having this problem?

Comment: "via USB" is too vague. There are countless styles of USB interface.

If what you are asking is how to make the Pi behave as a USB *device* that would identify as such to a Windows host, the answer is, you can't. Your best option is to get something like a Teensy3, program it to behave as an HID device, and interface the Pi to the Teensy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no official support for using the RPi as a "gadget" device. Presently, it can only be used as a host. There has been some [rumblings](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1212) about trying to get it working, but it's unlikely that you'll get what you need by the time this project is due.

The problem seems to be regarding drivers for the RPi, and I don't think that would be considered within the scope of the project.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any suggestions for alternative solutions?

Comment: @spectre-d: I have never created a host device myself, so no, unfortunately I do not. I'm definitely more software focused.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it is required and the project was not thoroughly reviewed before it was assigned.